# string into const uint8_t*

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, uint8t

I'm writing a program in C++/C for raspberry pi pico. Pico has a 2MB of flash memory and it's SDK provides a function which allows to write data to that memory:

```
void flash_range_program(uint32_t flash_offs, const uint8_t *data, size_t count)
```

Second parameter of that function is the data which we want to write in the memory. I want to save strings and floats in that memory, but I don't know what is the best (performance wise) way to convert `std::string` and `float` to `__const uint8_t*__`.

Comment: What do you need to convert? Based on that function signature alone I'd expect that I could pass in a `reinterpret_cast`ed pointer to the`c_str()` of a `std::string` (or the address of the `float` variable)

Comment: I wonder why you have a string in the first place and not a buffer of std::uint8_t. E.g std::array<std::uint8_t,N> or a std::vector becuase the API seems to imply you must pass binary data and not strings.

Comment: @UnholySheep I foresee some troubles with using a string as input for binary data (flashing will probably include non ascii/utf-8 characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `std::uint8_t` is `unsigned char` (as is usually the case), you are allowed to simply access the object representation of a `float` variable called `f` via

```
reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&f)
```

and the contents of a `std::string` variable called `s` via

```
reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s.c_str())
```

The corresponding sizes are `sizeof(f)` and `s.size()` (or `s.size()+1` if you want to store the null terminator of the string as well).

This is assuming of course that you want to store the object representation of the `float` variable. If you want to store a serialized representation instead, then first convert to a `std::string` in an appropriate format.

---

In the unlikely scenario that `uint8_t` is not an alias for `unsigned char` you are *not* allowed to substitute `unsigned char` with `uint8_t` in the shown casts. They would then cause aliasing violations and therefore undefined behavior when the values are accessed through the resulting pointers.

Comment: Are you sure that given is guaranteed? I thought only uint8_t /may/ be unsigned char (implementation defined).

Comment: @JeffGarrett Yes, I guess it is technically possible that if `CHAR_BIT == 8` (it is not allowed to be lower) there is an _extended unsigned integer type_ with the same width as `unsigned char` which could be used for `uint8_t`. Essentially the implementation could choose to make `uint8_t` strongly-typed, but I think implementations agree _not_ to do that.

Comment: OK, you've made me think more. The choice of the underlying type for uint8_t must be part of the ABI, so I think your "implementations agree"is absolutely true in the sense that e.g. the x84 ABI chooses unsigned char. And since it must be an integer type, it's either going to be char, unsigned char, or an extended integer type, And GCC doesn't define any extended integer types. (Though: I do not see how it requires CHAR_BIT to be different than 8.) So, anyways, my comment was too pedantic... :)

Comment: @JeffGarrett I meant that `CHAR_BIT` has to be 8, meaning it is required to not be smaller. If it could be smaller, then it could make sense for `uint8_t` to be a different wider type than `unsigned char`. (If `CHAR_BIT` is larger than `8` I think it is impossible for `uint8_t` to exist, since, if I remember correctly, it is also required to not contain any padding bits.)

Comment: Thank you @user17732522 The solution for string works very good. I didn't test the solution for float, because the pico's writing function require that the data to write is a multiple of 256B, so it requires some additional work and I decided that I will convert float to string anyway.